# wwwroot doesn't exist in inetpub

Tags: iis, localhost, wwwroot

I installed IIS on my computer, but when I try to load localhost on google chrome it's says
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module    IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070003
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
Config File    \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/
Physical Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

I also don't have wwwroot in my inetpub folder and I think that's why the error above appears. I created then my wwwroot folder in the ineptpub folder, but I have a new error: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: What's your operating system? Windows Home?

Comment: Do you enable Default Document and Directory Browsing on IIS?